# Creating Universal Fat Framework lipo: can't create temporary output file

Tags: ios, swift4, ios-frameworks, xcode9.1, lipo

On creating Fat framework from aggregate target, I am following the build phase script from this [gist link](https://gist.github.com/cromandini/1a9c4aeab27ca84f5d79) with minor changes on [my script link](https://github.com/kaushlendrapal/SwiftyLayouts/blob/master/SwiftyLayouts/Build-Phases/swiftyLayouts_universal_fat.sh).

On target build, Xcode is showing ***fetal error: lipo: can't create temporary output file: /${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}.lipo (No such file or directory)***

See image below for reference

[image: build error]

**[Updated the final working Script](https://github.com/kaushlendrapal/SwiftyLayouts/blob/master/SwiftyLayouts/Build-Phases/swiftyLayouts_universal_fat.sh)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Delete derived data folder.
3. Open Xcode and clean.
4. Build again.

Simply copying below script in `Run Script`, your workspace returns fat binary for me.

```
#!/bin/sh

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 3. Copy Swift modules (from iphonesimulator build) to the copied framework directory
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/." "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

# Step 6. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
```

This worked for me so far.

Comment: trying to build aggregate target from git framework project https://github.com/kaushlendrapal/SwiftyLayouts, getting same error.

Comment: Thanks! only removing swift module if condition working fine. How could i confirm that steps 3 passed.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! AFTER HOURS OF HAIR PULLING ITS YOU WHO SAVED MY NIGHT!

Comment: Did you try it in xcode 10.2 ? This builds for forever.

Comment: Same issue here, it doesn't finish building at x-1 of x tasks :(